# Filter two objects in array and append in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, antd

I have an array with objects that has dates. I have start and end date.
I want it to append on my calendar component. But I'm not sure how to get them both (start and end dates) to append. I can only get to filter the start date.

Here's my form
[image]

Here's my data after submitting the form

```
{
 category: "leave"
 colorCode: "#6f1e51"
 email: "sfe.bruce.logan@gmail.com"
 endDate: "2019-11-05"
 endTime: "10:48 AM"
 startDate: "2019-11-01"
 startTime: "10:49 AM"
 type: "Vacation Leave"
} {
 category: "leave"
 colorCode: "#f79f1f"
 email: "sfe.bruce.logan@gmail.com"
 endDate: "2019-11-10"
 endTime: "10:50 AM"
 startDate: "2019-11-05"
 startTime: "10:49 AM"
 type: "Sample Leave"
} {
 category: "leave"
 colorCode: "#f79f1f"
 email: "sfe.bruce.logan@gmail.com"
 endDate: "2019-11-20"
 endTime: "10:51 AM"
 startDate: "2019-11-10"
 startTime: "10:50 AM"
 type: "Sample Leave"
}
```

This is the code where I filter the startDate and compare it with the array of dates in the calendar

```
const getEmployeeLeaves = value => {
let employeeLeaves = [...isEmployeeLeave];

 const calendarDates = value.toString();
 const formatCalendarDates = moment(calendarDates).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

 const getDates = employeeLeaves.filter(
  item => item.startDate === formatCalendarDates
 );
};
```

And append it in the calendar using this function calling it in the props of the Calendar

```
const dateCellRender = value => {
let employeeLeaves = getEmployeeLeaves(value);

if (employeeLeaves && employeeLeaves.length) {
 return (
  <ul className="events">
   {employeeLeaves.map((item, i) => (
     <li key={i}>
      <p>
       {item.email}
      </p>
    </li>
   ))}
   </ul>
  );
} else {
  return <ul className="leaves"></ul>;
 }
};
```

This is the component. I'm using AntDesign calendar component

```
<Calendar
  dateCellRender={dateCellRender}
  monthCellRender={monthCellRender}
  onPanelChange={changeCalendarMode}
  onSelect={showLeaveListModal}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I think you're really close! I think you just need to update the logic in your filter function to return employeeLeaves that match startDate OR endDate.

```
const getEmployeeLeaves = value => {
  let employeeLeaves = [...isEmployeeLeave];

  const calendarDates = value.toString();
  const formatCalendarDates = moment(calendarDates).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

  return employeeLeaves.filter(
    item => item.startDate === formatCalendarDates || item.endDate === formatCalendarDates
  );
};
```

Comment: @Alyssa did this answer your question?